# Salvando informações de checkbox em arquivos TXT

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um software de O.S. onde dividi os principais problemas em  vários checkboxes. Todos os dados preenchidos na tela serão enviados para um arquivo de text, que logo depois será visualizado pelo chefe no Excel.

O meu problema é que eu não to conseguindo capturar as informações somente dos checkbox que foram marcados.

A minha duvida é: Como capturar as informações referentes somente aos checkbox que foram marcados e jogar em um arquivo de texto?

PS: Para identificar os checkbox, ao lado de cada um eu adicionei uma Label com a descrição do problema q o checkbox representa, não sei se é a maneira mais correta. Adicionei um código que montei a partir de um tutorial da Net, preciso capturar as informações referentes a cada checkbox que for marcado

```
private void BtSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = @"C:\\Users\\Core i3\\Desktop\\OS.Soluctions.txt";

        StreamWriter arq = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        arq.WriteLine("");
        arq.Write(TbNumeroOS.Text.ToUpper() + "," + maskedTextBox1.Text.ToUpper() + "," + maskedTextBox3.Text.ToUpper() + "," + TbSuporte.Text.ToUpper() + "," + maskedTextBox5.Text.ToUpper() + "," + maskedTextBox4.Text.ToUpper() + "," + CbListTec.Text.ToUpper() + "," + CbStatus.Text.ToUpper()
            + "," + label12.Text.ToUpper() + "," + label13.Text.ToUpper() + "," + label14.Text.ToUpper() + "," + label15.Text.ToUpper() + "," + label16.Text.ToUpper());


        TbNumeroOS.Clear();
        TbSuporte.Clear();
        maskedTextBox1.Clear();
        maskedTextBox3.Clear();
        maskedTextBox5.Clear();
        maskedTextBox4.Clear();

        arq.Close();
        arq.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Text Appended");
        MessageBox.Show("O.S. ADCIONADA COM SUCESSO", "ATENÇÃO!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CbSupUsuario_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CbSupUsuario.Checked == true)
            label12.Text = "Suporte ao Usuário";

    }

    private void CbMaqEquip_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CbMaqEquip.Checked == true)
            label13.Text = "Máquina/Equipamento";
        else
            label13.Text = "";
    }

    private void CbFaltaInter_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CbFaltaInter.Checked == true)
            label14.Text = "Falta de Internet";
        else
            label14.Text = "";
    }

    private void CbConfigEquip_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CbConfigEquip.Checked == true)
            label15.Text = "Configuracao de Equipamento";
        else
            label15.Text = "";
    }

    private void CbAtuaSoftWare_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CbAtuaSoftWare.Checked == true)
            label16.Text = "Atualizacao de Software";
        else
            label16.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Estou fazendo com WinForms

Comment: E quais informações você precisa pegar dos checkboxes? Eles estão dentro de algum container (um controle pai)?

Comment: adicionei mais código pra você conseguir entender melhor a estrutura que estou tentando montar

Comment: Seu código não me diz nada. Se você respondesse o que eu perguntei seria muito mais fácil.

Comment: Eles estão sem Controle, desculpe a demora pra responder, é que estou aprendendo na porrada, mas confiante

Comment: Jovem, tudo bem você não saber/entender algo. Mas tentar desenvolver algo sem ao menos entender a base da tecnologia/linguagem/framework é tiro no pé. Também atente quando vier pedir ajuda, escrever algumas linhas de texto (confuso, diga-se de passagem) e colocar um bloco de código não é suficiente na maioria dos casos. É preciso que você nos explique bem o que está tentando fazer e como está tentando fazer, qual o comportamento esperado e onde está a sua dificuldade. Pare pra notar quantas perguntas eu fiz pra você, sem elas é impossível responder sua pergunta, isso já é motivo para fechá-la

Comment: Coloquei uma observação no final da minha resposta. É tudo o que eu consigo responder com as informações que você deu até agora. Pode comentar se tiver alguma dúvida ou quiser adicionar informações no seu problema. Por hora, é o máximo que eu consigo fazer.

Comment: Já estou me encontrando, as CheckBox estão fora do Container Pai, estão todas dentro de um Painel. Foi isso q consegui identificar

Comment: Ótimo. Você só se confundiu numa coisa. Não existe **container pai**, digo, não existe um controle pai para o form, isso é um conceito relativo, o seu painel **é o container pai dos checkboxes**. Agora veja a minha resposta, troque o `parent` pelo nome do painel.

Answer (score 2):

Faça um loop no controle pai dos checkboxes e obtenha a informação dos que forem marcados

```
string conteudo = "";

foreach(var control in parent.Controls)
{
    var chkbox = control as CheckBox; //Se o control não for um checkbox, retorna null

    if(chkbox != null) 
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\arquivo.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {             
            writer.WriteLine($"{chkbox.Text},");
        }
    }
}
```

**Observações**: `parent` é o controle "pai" dos checkboxes, se você não colocou os mesmos dentro de um controle pai (container, ou seja lá como queira chamar), troque **`parent`** por **`this`**, o `this` faz referência ao form em si, então, o *loop* vai passar por **todos os controles dentro do form**.

Answer (score 1):

Como não conheço o componente (nessa sua plataforma) usando a mesma lógica que eu uso em Delphi posso lhe apresentar uma solução!

Como se trata de lógica, deve funcionar em qualquer linguagem.

```
{faço um faço em todos os componentes do form}
for i := 0 to Components.Count - 1 do
begin {se o componente for um ChekBox}
  if (Components[i].ClassType = TCheckBox) then
  begin
    if (TCheckBox(Components[i]).Checked = True) then
    begin
      {escreve aqui no arquivo}     
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Um simples laço pode resolver seu problema;

Agora você também pode fazer tudo de forma recursiva:

```
if (CheckBoxX.Checek = True) then
  {escreve aqui no arquivo}  
if (CheckBoxY.Checek = True) then
  {escreve aqui no arquivo}  
if (CheckBoxZ.Checek = True) then
  {escreve aqui no arquivo}  
if (CheckBoxH.Checek = True) then
  {escreve aqui no arquivo}
```

O ruim é que sempre que implementar novas opções sempre devera implementar a escrita do arquivo.

Comment: Nessa segunda opção que você citou  eu poderia pegar pra ele receber no proprio CheckboxY  e citar ele , porque além das informações dos checkbox, existem as das textbox ta tela, no caso, o Excel só consegue montar se tiverem separadas por vírgula as informações,

Comment: Sim, sim, o problema da segunda é o que mencionei, sempre que implementar novos CheckBox terá que implementar a escrita! Dinâmico economiza código e facilita manutenção!